# Java button actions in multiple classes

Tags: java, swing, oop, button, methods

Working in Java: I have a `JFrame` class, and separate classes for my two `JPanels` that are added to the `JFrame`.  One of the `JPanel` classes has some buttons in it, which can interact with each other(when I click on one button, it can disable another button).  However, I can't figure out how to get the button to call a method in the other `JPanel` (written in a separate class).

So, my program look like this:

JFrame

- Jpanel1
- Jpanel2 - This class has my buttons in it, I'm trying to get them to interact with the JPanel1 object.

Any tips appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Showing your code would be useful. Posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be better.

Comment: You probably should not have 1 `JFrame` and 2 `JPanel` *classes* so much as *instances* (of the standard component).  Also, it would pay to make your class/instance names less abstract, in that panel 1 might be `userDetails`and panel 2 might be `userControls`, which gives us a better idea of what the ultimate goal is, and thereby a better chance to provide optimal advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to pass an instance of (to use your terminology) Jpanel1 into Jpanel2. This doesn't have to be done in the constructor, you can have a `setConnectedPanel(JPanel)` method, for example.

Here's some code that demonstrates what you want to do:

*MyFrame.java*

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

  public MyFrame() {
    ReactionPanel rp = new ReactionPanel();
    ActionPanel ap = new ActionPanel(rp);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    add(ap);
    add(rp);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new MyFrame();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

*ActionPanel.java*

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ActionPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
  private ReactionPanel rp;
  private JButton button;

  public ActionPanel(ReactionPanel rp) {
    this.rp = rp;
    button = new JButton("Click");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(button);
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(button)) {
      rp.react();
    }
  }
}
```

*ReactionPanel.java*

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ReactionPanel extends JPanel {
  private JLabel label;

  public ReactionPanel() {
    label = new JLabel("PING");
    this.add(label);
  }

  public void react() {
    if(label.getText().equals("PING")) {
      label.setText("PONG");
    } else {
      label.setText("PING");
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I tend to override all of my JFrames/JPanels when I write Swing GUIs as I find it easier and more flexible but YMMV.

Comment: No worries. If it fully answers your question, you should click the green tick next to this answer. :)